# data frames with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to Python and came across an interesting piece of code that I am trying to understand in greater detail. My data frame looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'business': ['FX','a','CR'], 'A/L': ['A','A','L']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data
```

Someone very kindly posted the following piece of code on this site:

```
cols=data.columns
pd.DataFrame({col: data[col].str.contains('#') for col in cols})
```

I understand what the code inside the pd.DataFrame is doing. However, I cannot find any documentation on how the for loop works in the above context. This does not look like a list comprehension even though it works something like a list comprehension.

Can someone point me to some documentation / tutorial that explains how to use the syntax above ?

Comment: its a dict comprehension. :)

Comment: with `cols=data.columns` you save your column headers: 'business' and 'A/L', then you are looping over this colmns and look if a '#' is inside, use `print(pd.DataFrame({col: data[col].str.contains('#') for col in cols})` to see what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not list comprehension instead there are two concepts used,

1. [[Dictionary comprehension]](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-comprehension/)
2. [[pandas.Series.str.contains]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Whereas the following code,

```
{col: data[col].str.contains('#') for col in cols}
```

Iterates over the list df.columns with the variable col and add it to the resulting list. This syntax is Dictionary comprehension.

**Example of dictionary comprehension:**

```
myDict = {x: x**2 for x in [1,2,3,4,5]} 
print (myDict)
```

**Output**

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a dict comprehension.
Dictionaries allow you to map one value onto another which is what you're doing in your code.
The official [python documentation covers this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with a neat example

`{x: x**2 for x in (2, 4, 6)}`

which returns a dict : `{2: 4, 4: 16, 6: 36}` where `x` is mapped to `x**2`

essentially what you're doing here is,

`{key: value that you want for the key, value in dict.items()}`